# How enable JIRA service on Gitlab Project services tab?

Tags: jira, gitlab

I'm trying to integrate JIRA issue tracker with Gitlab and following instructions from [official docs](https://about.gitlab.com/features/#compare).

My `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb' configuration file looks like

> gitlab_rails['issues_tracker_jira'] = true
>
> gitlab_rails['issues_tracker_jira_title'] = "Atlassian Jira"
>
> gitlab_rails['issues_tracker_jira_project_url'] =
>   "http://localhost:7777/issues/?jql=project=:issues_tracker_id"
>
> gitlab_rails['issues_tracker_jira_issues_url'] =
>   "http://localhost:7777/browse/:id"
>
> gitlab_rails['issues_tracker_jira_new_issue_url'] =
>   "http://localhost:7777/secure/CreateIssue.jspa"

JIRA web app installed and running at localhost:7777

Modifying gitlab.rb file as showed above  **enabled JIRA in Setting tab** as expected but **services tab doesn't contain JIRA**. Of course, I choose Atlassian Jira in Features, specified jira project name (same as gitlab project name) saved changes and in Project services tab saw Assembla, Atlassian Bamboo and others but **didn't see JIRA**. What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

As VonC pointed out, CE doesn't support JIRA fully. But, according to CE and EE [comparison](https://about.gitlab.com/features/#compare), CE still supports JIRA partially, in particular, mention JIRA ticket from Gitlab. As I understand, I still able to point issues to my JIRA instance and add issues in JIRA but **I  have to manually create project in JIRA and gitlab project name must be the same with the JIRA project name**, am I right? I think so, because when I do it everything works the ony problem is `log-in-problem` described below.

Also, linking to JIRA doesn't work until I'm not logged in to JIRA. **Is there any way to provide JIRA credentials to Gitlab CE?**

Comment: Do you have GitLab EE (Enterprise Edition)? Because Jira support is only available in EE: http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira.html

Comment: The link is doc/ee: ee stands for Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point, also I found CE and EE comparison and still have some questions. Please, see update.

Comment: What version of GitLab are you using? (as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6975)

Comment: Regarding the authentication, this *might* help a bit: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1240

Comment: The latest 7.6.2 omnibus installation.

Comment: There are two kinds of Jira support:
1. Linking to jira in the comments. Works for CE and EE
2. Closing tickets via commits: works only with EE as mentioned before

Regaring 1: The project name itself can be defined on a repository basis (via Project Settings => Lightweight issue tracking system for this project => Jira).

Comment: @volker, I specified project name in  Project Settings => Lightweight issue tracking system for this project, but when I go to issues, JIRA writes `not such value` i.e. I still have to manually create project in JIRA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are using gitlab-ce 8.2.2-ce.0 and JIRA 6.4.11. I didn't have to configure anything in gitlab.rb.

First, configure the template so you don't have to do everything for each new project:
http://localhost:7777/admin/application_settings/services

Open "JIRA" and exactly set this (including the ##-stuff - don't replace it):

`Project url: http://localhost:7777/browse/#project-name#
Issues url: http://localhost:7777/browse/:id
New issue url: http://localhost:7777/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa?selectedProjectId=#project-id#`

Then for each project, go to "Project > Settings > Services", activate JIRA and adapt the settings to use the correct project name and ID.

> gitlab project name must be the same with the JIRA project name, am I right?

No, this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Jira is configurable since [GitLab 13.3 (August 2020)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63549580/6309).

And with [GitLab 16.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/02/15/gitlab-16-9-released/#enable-jira-issues-at-the-group-level) (February 2024):

> ### Enable Jira issues at the group level
>
> With this release, you can enable Jira issues for all projects in a GitLab group. Previously, you could only enable Jira issues for each GitLab project individually.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira/configure.html#view-jira-issues) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/325715).